# How do I use string.StartsWith() when I only have some parts of the comparison string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, startswith

I'm working with the IRC-protocol, and I am trying to interpret the server messages. If I for instance got the following string:

":USERNAME!~IP PRIVMSG #CHANNELNAME :MESSAGE"

How can I use string.StartsWith if I don't know the variables: USERNAME, IP, CHANNELNAME or MESSAGE?

I would like to do something like this: (I'm aware that this doesn't work)

```
if(MessageString.StartsWith(":*!~* PRIVMSG #*"))
```

Comment: This is a job for regular expressions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx

Comment: You should take a look at regular expressions

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @Robin If you Google "regex tutorial" you can probably find a lot of resources on your own, now that you know what you're looking for :)

Comment: I know what Regular expressions are, I know how to use them when doing other stuff. However I don't know what the terminology is for this specific problem, and only searching "regex tutorial" will give me a lot more information that I need.

Comment: It doesn't require a super-complex regex, assuming you know how to use character classes. Why not give it your best shot, and if you can't quite get it, we can help you out.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use StartsWith. I suggest to parse the string by e.g. splitting it into tokens. That way you can check wether the PrivMsg string is contained in the token-List.

There might be libraries allready to parse IRC Messages. Have you checked https://launchpad.net/ircdotnet?

Answer (score 1):

You may try using regular expressions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

```
  // Check this regular expression: 
  // I've tried to reconstruct it from wild card in the question 
  Regex regex = new Regex(@":.*\!~.* PRIVMSG \#.*");

  Match m = regex.Match(":USERNAME!~IP PRIVMSG #CHANNELNAME :MESSAGE");

  if (m.Success) {
    int startWith = m.Index;
    int length = m.Length;
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, using the [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.aspx) class.

```
var regex = new Regex(
    @":(?<userName>[^!]+)!~(?<ip>[^ ]+) PRIVMSG #(?<theRest>[\s\S]+)");
var match = regex.Match(MessageString);
if (match.Success)
{
    var userName = match.Groups["userName"].Value;
    var ip = match.Groups["ip"].Value;
    var theRest = match.Groups["theRest"].Value;

    // do whatever
}
```

I would also take a look at the [MSDN page for regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) in .Net.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a separator after the words you don't know and parse a string from the main one containing only the message.

Comment: I...can't even tell what this is supposed to mean. All I'm getting is "parse it," which isn't even close to an answer.